# How does C store the information into a file really?

Tags: c, file-io, format

In the simple code below, I'm writing an int number (10) into a file and then reading it back to make sure it's done successfully and it is. However, when I open the file (tried both notepad++ and vscode) I see something like this:

```
???
```

Here's the code:

```
int main(){

    int var = 10;
    FILE* fp = fopen("testfile","w");
    rewind(fp);
    fwrite(&var,sizeof(int),1,fp);

    fflush(fp);
    fclose(fp);

    int var2 = 0;

    fopen("testfile","r+");
    fread(&var2,sizeof(int),1,fp);

    printf("num: %d\n",var2);

return 0;
}
```

Of course I thought maybe it's written in a special format which vscode is unable to recognize, but recently I learned coding a simple database, and it used just the same way to save the records in files and when you opened its output file with vscode, it showed both ???s AND the information, however, here it shows only ???s WITHOUT the information. So although it seems be a very basic problem, I can't find the answer to it, so how is 10 really stored in that file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a hex editor to inspect the file. `fwrite()` simply writes the objects binary representation byte per byte. If you want a file that is human-readable, use `fprintf()`.

Comment: `fwrite(&var,sizeof(int),1,fp);` writes the integer as a binary value. This is not text, and it is useless trying to look for `10` with a text editor.

Comment: Thanks guys, so may I ask why that database program showed the text as well? I can give the address to its code if it's needed.

Comment: When you write a `char` array that contains characters with `fwrite()` a text editor will be able to display them because the binary representation doesn't differ from the character value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write to the file with `fwrite`, it reads the raw bytes that make up `var` and writes those to disk.  This is the **binary representation** of the number.

If you use a tool like `od`, it will print out the bytes the files contains:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$ od -tx1 testfile 
0000000 0a 00 00 00
0000004
```

You can see here that the first byte contains the value 10 and the next 3 contain the value 0.  This tells us that an `int` takes up 4 bytes and is stored in little-endian format, meaning the least significant byte comes first.

Had you instead uses `fprintf` to write the value:

```
fprintf(fp, "%d\n", var);
```

It would have written the text representation to the file.  The file would then look something like this:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$ cat testfile 
10
[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$ od -tx1 testfile 
0000000 31 30 0a
0000003
```

We can see here that printing the file shows readable text, and `od` shows us the ASCII codes for the characters `'1'` and `'0'`, as well as a newline.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing a *binary* file. It cannot be read with an editor. The value `10` is probably stored as `0x0000000A` or `0x0A000000` something like that, depending on if the system is big or small endian.

But the point is that it is stored in binary format and not text format.

If you open this file in a text editor, it will likely be interpreted as three NULL characters and then a LF (line feed) character.

Comment: Thank you, so may I ask why that database program showed the text as well? I'm sure it used fwrite. (I can give the address to its code if it's needed)

Comment: I suppose you wrote character arrays then.